# Как автоматизировать сбор конфигов с коммутаторов через GUI?

Tags: python, linux, gui, switch

Суть проблемы следующая.

Хочу написать скрипт на python который будет 2 раза в месяц автоматически собирать конфиги коммутаторов.
На данный момент я это делаю ручками, что контрпродуктивно и утомительно.

Проблема в том что у нас установлены коммутаторы HP 1820 с доступом только через  GUI интерфейс (веб-страница). По другому к ним подключиться никак нельзя.

Насколько я знаю это можно сделать через библиотеку selenium или вроде еще можно через api.

Может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой. Как это лучше сделать? Что использовать ? Может вы предложите какие то другие варианты как это стоит сделать?

Comment: Хоть бы модель коммутаторов указали, чтобы было что искать

Comment: модель свича HP 1820

Comment: Возможно будет достаточно посылать правильные http запросы. Тут надо открыть режим разработчика в браузере и посмотреть какие запросы отправляются для получения нужной информации. Ну если в документации по этому поводу ничего нет, разумеется.

Comment: https://github.com/BookGin/hp1820-cli не оно?